# Time step too small in LTspice simulation

Tags: circuit-design, power-electronics, ltspice

I face the "time step too small" error while simulating this circuit. I don't think it should be super hard to solve.

The schematic is for an isolated AC dimmer and consists of some optocouplers, a 555 timer, FETs, and two grounds - a normal ground and LV_GND. If I bridge these grounds together things will solve, but that's not what I'm going to build.

I've tried the gear solver etc., but they don't seem to work.

.asc file: https://file.io/zAzXYz1sMGye

[image]

Comment: You have a floating section of circuitry with respect to GND which SPICE doesn't like. Connect a 10meg resistor between LV_GND and GND and see if that helps.

Comment: Why did you delete the file? Why not copy-paste it here, instead? Use ``` as delimiters (before and after the pasted text). Also, What are you trying to accomplish? The two transistors short out the source to ground if they end up conducting. I doubt they will, not with those resistors for the optos. Plus, I really feel for `U1` being driven the way it is. What value does `V1` have?

Answer (score 2):

You are facing a problem with sharp transitions from poorly modeled components or inductors. In real life, there is also a capacitance associated with each node, which helps to make the transitions smoother.

Add an option to your LTSpice simulation in the following way:
[image]

It will add a shunt capacitance to each node of 1fF. I tried it, and it works perfectly. For your application, a capacitance of up to 100fF will have neglected effects.

Answer (score 1):

Too much of the circuit is floating and needs to be better referenced. V1 should be referenced to GND.

Also, Try putting a large resistor (like a 1Meg) between LV_GND and GND. Check the voltage, if it's more than a few 10mV then you might want to combine grounds for simulation purposes.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The circuit creates a virtual ground at the anode of D2, if I add a ground at the neut of V1 that isn't really an accurate representation of the circuit and I immagine there will be knock on effects. I tried doing this and it doesn't work anways.